# Error: NG0100 al cambiar la ruta según el rol en angular

Tags: angular, typescript, aplicación-web

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en angular.

El problema es que tengo un logo que tiene la funcion de redirigir a la pagina principal dependiendo del rol que lo esté usando (que haya iniciado sesion). Para esto debo cambiar el valor de la variable de forma dinamica generando el error NG0100.

El logo tiene este codigo :

```
   <a class="navbar-brand mr-2 mt-2  mt-lg-0" id="navbarBrand" routerLink="{{hrefLogo}}" >
               <img
                 src="../assets/logo.png"
                 height="40"
                 alt="50"
                 loading="lazy"
                 width="90"
               />
             </a>
```

La variable hrefLogo cambia al momento de que se detecta quien inició sesion, un ejemplo general del codigo sería este;

```
esRol1(){
....
this.hrefLogo = "rol1/main"
...
}

esRol2(){
....
this.hrefLogo = "rol2/main"
...
}
```

Entonces si entro con rol1 y luego con rol2 genera todo el tiempo el siguiente error:

> ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

La pregunta es :

**Hay alguna forma de realizar esto evitando ese error o de alguna mejor manera?**

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

> El error se da en general  cuando cualquier cambio de
> valores se descubre después de que la vista es inicializada Si
> inicializamos valores de variables y tratamos de cambiarlos  después de
> que la vista fue inicializada y usamos para ello al método ngAfterViewInit  o
> ngOnChange . Puede solucionarse si usamos el  Constructor o  ngOnInit
> para definir los valores de las variables

this.hrefLogo = "rol1/main" y this.hrefLogo = "rol2/main"

[NG0100: Expression has changed](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100)

Comment: Lo intente usar en ngOnInit y el constructor pero seguía saliendo lo mismo. Hay que considerar que la ruta cambia luego de identificar al usuario que está iniciando sesión, por lo que no puedo solo darle el valor a las variables, tiene que antes pasar por un if para saber si esRol1() o esRol2()

Comment: Podes mostrar el codigo que usas para capturar el cambio.Hay muchisimas formas posibles y no sabemos cual usas

Comment: yo en general uso CanActivate con Guard